# How to facilitate a no-polling messaging between two users on PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Server: NGINX/PHP running Laravel 5

Let's assume I have two users on different computers with sessions to the application.

- User 1: makes an ajax call that is handled by one of the server controllers.
- User 2: needs to get notified of this as soon as user 1 made this call to the controller.

Now, user 2 can have a javascript polling mechanism which asks the question "has this happened?" repeatedly, but ideally I'd like to avoid the constant calling and have him/her notified upon occurance instead.

Is there any way to have like an "open socket" for user 2 to be notified when certain events occur in the controller?

Ideally I'd like to avoid installing a third party messaging system, XMPP Etc on my server. Is there any best practice where this functionality can be achieved?

Comment: Two common options are using websockets in JavaScript or using long-HTTP requests. You never finish the HTTP request and close out the page. You keep it open as long as you can.

Comment: Sounds like a job for socket.io to me

Comment: Ratchet may fit your requirement . http://socketo.me/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets.io is indeed a good solution for this. I'll be using it on both the server side (Separate NodeJS server for this), and the client javascript side.